# What's this insect?

Tags: entomology

Found on my indoor egg plant. I also have aphids, spider mites, and psyllids on it, and am hoping it's a predator like a ladybug larva but the colours are wrong. It's about 6 mm long. Found in New Zealand.

[image: Insect]

Comment: We can't identify anything if you don't give us your exact location. "China" is not specific enough, "southern Beijing city" is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The photo isn't very good, but I'm almost sure that's a hemipteran (a planthopper, leafhoppter, depends on the type of hemipteran, I can't say). And it seems to be a nymph (a imature individual).

Answer (score 4):

As Lfppfs said it seems to be a nymph of planthopper, [Dictyonissus griphus](http://www.austinbug.com/survey/2012/survey5-3-2012.html).

[image]

[This website](http://bugguide.net/node/view/541373/bgimage) has more pictures. If you are interested you can find fully formed (matured) *Dictyonissus griphus*.

Comment: Nice picture, looks very much like mine.

Comment: It usually has a long fibrous white tail, as you might have seen from the rest of the pictures I linked. I wonder what might have happened to its tail.